# How to get Jenkins changelog_data in InfluxDB

Tags: jenkins, influxdb, changelog

I am using InfluxDB for collecting Jenkins build metrics.

Now I’ve requirement of collecting changelog_data from Jenkins. This table contains data --

```
affected_paths
commit_count
commit_messages
culprits
```

I’ve tried to add `changelog` plugin in maven, ran `mvn changelog:changlog` command which has generated `changelog.xml` but in InfluxDB not getting any data while running

`select * from changelog_data`

I've also installed `git-changelog` plugin in Jenkins - https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-changelog/ but not getting how to use it in Jenkins scripted pipeline for this use-case.

Could anyone please advise how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem here, no additional plugin should be needed as it clearly states in the plugin documentation.

In addition to this, I don't have the junit_data measurement available either on 2.3

using multi-branch-pipelines from bitbucket

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hmm ok got it, I think should come by default these data. For your query about junit_data, I have that. For this, you'd need to run ```mvn test``` and then publish this report using ```junit "**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml"```. Then it would be available in InfluxDB - jenkins_data table under jenkins_db database.

Comment: thanks, I also needed to set a Global Variable LOG_JUNIT_RESULTS to true for the test result data
I opened a bug with the plugin owners here regarding the changelog data here -> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62277 follow it for updates